# Bootstrap Datepicker not clearing for date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I'm using this [datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) *(version 1.6.1)* in a project. I have a button that clears all inputs in a form and [according to the documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/methods.html#cleardates), all I need to do is

```
$(".selector").datepicker("clearDates");
```

This is working fine for a single datepicker field but it doesn't work for a date-range.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".date").datepicker({
    todayBtn: "linked",
    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    orientation: "bottom",
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy"
  });

  $(document).on("click", "button", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".date").datepicker("clearDates");
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.input-group {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='input-group date'>
  <input name='single' class='single basic-input form-control' placeholder='MM/DD/YYYY' autocomplete='off'>
  <div class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span></div>
</div>

<div class='input-group input-daterange date'>
  <input name='start' class='start basic-input form-control' placeholder='MM/DD/YYYY' autocomplete='off'>
  <div class='input-group-addon'>to</div>
  <input name='end' class='end basic-input form-control' placeholder='MM/DD/YYYY' autocomplete='off'>
</div>

<button id='clear-params' type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-block' aria-label='Clear'>
  <span>Clear</span>
</button>
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vy6ptnmj/92/) if you prefer to debug over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you were missing `selector classes` in daterange

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".date").datepicker({
    todayBtn: "linked",
    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    orientation: "bottom",
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy"
  });

  $(document).on("click", "button", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".dateselector").datepicker("clearDates");
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.input-group {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='input-group date'>
  <input name='single' class='single basic-input form-control dateselector' placeholder='MM/DD/YYYY' autocomplete='off'>
  <div class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span></div>
</div>

<div class='input-group input-daterange date'>
  <input name='start' class='start basic-input form-control dateselector' placeholder='MM/DD/YYYY' autocomplete='off'>
  <div class='input-group-addon'>to</div>
  <input name='end' class='end basic-input form-control dateselector' placeholder='MM/DD/YYYY' autocomplete='off'>
</div>

<button id='clear-params' type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-block' aria-label='Clear'>
  <span>Clear</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Darn. All the while I thought the class has to be on the parent element and not the input itself. Thanks!

Comment: Your edit actually messed it up. The two date ranges are no longer linked if you remove the `date` class on the parent element. Your first answer was the correct one. You have to have the `.date` on the parent and both inputs.

Comment: yeah.. was just experimenting

Comment: @uom-pgregorio check updated answer, calling datepicker only on intended elements. lets leave `date` to be used by plugin.

Comment: I would say a better solution would be to do `$(".date input").datepicker("clearDates");`. It's just so when I decide to add another date field I won't have to modify the JS file.

Comment: nope.. you are unnecessarily running it on divs.. If you need you can some common class on inputs

Comment: @uom-pgregorio check updated answer, used common class `dateselector`

Comment: Yes I prefer this version. Thanks!